# What percent of planned development time should be allocated to usability testing?

Tags: usability-testing, planning

In planning the design of a hardware and/or software project, roughly how much time should I expect will go to usability testing?

Also, how is the typical amount of time affected (increased or decreased) by:

- Size of project (ie total development time excluding testing),
- Hardware vs software,
- Size of anticipated userbase (10, 100, 1000, etc),
- Number of engineers working on development?

I think the question [What is a good method/formula for estimating how much time a usability test will require?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/what-is-a-good-method-formula-for-estimating-how-much-time-a-usability-test-will) seems also related. In contrast to that question, however, I am interested in aggregate testing time for an entire project, rather than a single test.

Comment: Just as a side note - usability testing is typically part of the evaluation/testing stage, not the development stage. Then, I don't think you'll get any useful answer here - real world projects are guided by various constraints (time, budget). Every project is assess based on some research into the requirements - a conceptual product will call for much more testing. There are also uncontrolled variables in your questions - like how experienced the developers are? How many user groups there are, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Izhaki That's interesting... I would think of including testing in development because it is something that has to be done before delivering a product. That's true, there are many other variables, so it won't be possible to say for sure. But I'm wondering if anyone has a rough (even if very rough) guess, perhaps based on experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ever, it depends.

It depends on what your goal is.  If your goal is simple usability testing to verify that you've met your usability goals for the research, then your need will be low.  If your goal is to better understand what product you should be building and doing research along the way to ensure that you're building the right product, then your need is higher.

It depends on whether you want just usability testing, or whether you want user experience research.  Usability testing is but one arrow in the quiver of a user experience researcher.  Usability testing considers whether a feature, group of features, or product (depending on the scope of your product) meets its usability goals.  User experience research includes methodologies that are both formative and summative.  In short, formative research helps you determine what product to build, whereas summative research (which includes usability studies) helps you determine whether you have built it correctly.  The later that a usability study is done, the less likely you are to be able to address problems that come up.  The earlier that research is done, you have more room to be able to address issues in the overall design of the product, the mental models that you are using, and the workflows that you are designing your product to address.

It depends on the scope of your project.  A simple game for a mobile phone requires less user research than an enterprise product with millions of lines of code.

It does not depend on the size of your userbase.  It does depend on whether those users will have different interactions with your product.  For example, a simple game for a mobile phone could have millions of users, but it won't require much in the way of user research.  An enterprise product could only have 100,000 users, but if there are five different types of users who use the product in very different ways (that is, their workflows are different), then you will probably need a lot more user research.

It depends on how many designers are involved in your product.  If you don't have any designers, then you'll have to consider how (or if) you will address the results from the usability test.  What will you do if the usability study was conducting on live code, and it reveals that 70% of your users are unable to complete an important task?  You have to answer this question for yourself.

If your plan is simply to contract a usability study, you will learn something during the course of the study, and you might make a slightly better product as a result of the study.  If your plan is to hire a researcher to work on your product full-time, you have the opportunity to do the right research at the right time to answer the right question, and thus build a better product.

Answer (score 0):

In *Rocket surgery made easy* author Steve Krug says that a morning per month for testing and debriefing (preparation excluded) is the minimum.